# Numba inserts impossible values

Tags: python, numpy, numba

```py
@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def fn(A, V, out):
    for i in prange(out.shape[0]):
        for j in prange(out.shape[1]):
            out[i, j] = V[A[i, j]]
```

The above will, occasionally *but consistently*, insert impossible values from `V` into `out`; `out` is initialized to zeros, and `V` is confirmed to be within e.g. `0` and `5`, yet after `fn()`,  `out` will have values like `674`, `-1538853402`. By "consistently" I mean same `A` & `V` always yield same `out`. It occurs with both `int32` and `int64` (latter has greater extreme values).

What's the deal? It was on Windows 10 64 bit, Python 3.7.9, NumPy 1.19.2, and Numba 0.52.0.

---

**Full code**:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, prange

@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def fn(A, V, out):
    for i in prange(out.shape[0]):
        for j in prange(out.shape[1]):
            out[i, j] = V[A[i, j]]

#%%###########################################################
A = np.round(np.abs(np.random.randn(240, 10000))).astype(int)
V = np.arange(A.max()).astype(A.dtype)
out = np.zeros(A.shape, dtype=A.dtype)

print("A:", A.min(), A.max())
print("V:", V.min(), V.max())
print("out:", out.min(), out.max())
fn(A, V, out)
print("out:", out.min(), out.max())
print("number of extremes:", (np.abs(out) > V.max()).sum())
```

It was rerun several times for extreme values. I've not tried without `prange` or with `parallel=False` as it's extremely slow, but they shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of your script gives:

```
A: 0 5
V: 0 4
```

So `A` can take the value `5`. Thus when you make the assignment `out[i, j] = V[A[i, j]]` you will sometimes assign the value `v[5]`, which does not exist, hence the extreme values.

You would get this error without the parallel execution:

> IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5

You can fix the issue by modifying the definition of `V`: `V = np.arange(A.max()+1).astype(A.dtype)`.

Comment: Right... I see insecurities were inherited along speed from C.